# Langchain error: 'FieldInfo' object has no attribute 'split_documents'

Tags: visual-studio-code, text, split, langchain

After running the streamlit I got an error saying: AttributeError: 'FieldInfo' object has no attribute 'split_documents'
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vb5iE.png)

```
class WebpageQATool(BaseTool):
    name = "query_webpage"
    description = "Browse a webpage and retrieve the information and answers relevant to the question. Please use bullet points to list the answers"
    text_splitter: RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter = Field(default_factory=_get_text_splitter)
    qa_chain: BaseCombineDocumentsChain

    def _run(self, url: str, question: str) -> str:
        response = requests.get(url)
        page_content = response.text
        print(page_content)
        docs = [Document(page_content=page_content, metadata={"source": url})]
        web_docs = self.text_splitter.split_documents(docs)
        results = []
        for i in range(0, len(web_docs), 4):
            input_docs = web_docs[i:i+4]
            window_result = self.qa_chain({"input_documents": input_docs, "question": question}, return_only_outputs=True)
            results.append(f"Response from window {i} - {window_result}")
        results_docs = [Document(page_content="\n".join(results), metadata={"source": url})]
        print(results_docs)
        return self.qa_chain({"input_documents": results_docs, "question": question}, return_only_outputs=True)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1OIr.png)

Comment: try changing this line text_splitter: RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter = _get_text_splitter